# Create date time interval

Tags: php, datetime

I need to create DateTime interval to compare it with date difference. Is something like this possible?

```
$week = new \DateTime("1 week");
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking? Did you try this already?

Comment: I am sorry, I just tried what i wrote and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use [**DateInterval**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class instead. While you cannot pass the relative timeformats such as `'1 week'` into its constructor directly, there's a useful static method [**createFromDateString()**](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) that supports such syntax:

```
$weekInterval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');
```

The problem is that `DateInterval` instances are not comparable in PHP (check [this feature request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49914) for details):

```
$someInterval = (new \DateTime('2015-09-14'))->diff(new \DateTime('2015-09-13'));
var_dump($weekInterval > $someInterval); // false somehow
```

`DateTime` instances are comparable, however. So one possible workaround is making a comparison between the results of adding two `DateInterval` to the same fixed date. For example:

```
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
var_dump($now->add($weekInterval) > $now->add($someInterval)); // true
```

[**Eval.in**](https://eval.in/432872) demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `diff();` function in the `DateTime` class.

```
$dateOne = new DateTime('2015-10-11');
$dateTwo = new DateTime('2014-10-13');
$interval = $dateOne->diff($dateTwo);

echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

**Comparing UNIX TimeStamp**

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("@" . $someOtherTimeStamp);
$endTime = new DateTime("@" . time());
$interval = $dateTime->diff($endTime);
```

**Reading Material**

[`diff();`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)